# MySql query executes two times?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having a problem, i got the following code:

```
$host = "127.0.0.1"; $dbname = "test"; $user = "root"; $pass = "";
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET NAMES UTF8");

mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `value`) VALUES ( MD5(NOW()),  MD5(NOW()) )");
```

and it executes twice, i cannot figure out why.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without mysql or apache logs. Please show us them.

Comment: apache:
`test: 127.0.0.1 [11/Mar/2014:12:10:36 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"
test: 127.0.0.1 [11/Mar/2014:12:10:42 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: IS this all or you are calling it twice somewhere else?

Comment: There's lack of information. You should release portion of your PHP codes too as the codes seems to be fine at this moment. It might be some incorrect loop or something else.

Comment: mysql:
`140311 11:57:51     2 Connect root@localhost on test
      2 Query SET NAMES UTF8
      2 Query INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `value`) VALUES ( MD5(1394531871.1075),  MD5(1394531871.1075) )
      2 Quit 
      3 Connect root@localhost on test
      3 Query SET NAMES UTF8
      3 Query INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `value`) VALUES ( MD5(1394531871.1368),  MD5(1394531871.1368) )
      3 Quit `

Comment: how are you executing this code, using url or any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, apache tries to retrieve `favicon.ico` and, possibly, you got some rewrite rules that redirect to your `index` file. Try to add `favicon.ico` or update your rewrite rules.